# Simulate "shift" pressing key on checkbox to select multiple rows

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events, checkbox, keyevent

I have the following input

```
 <input type="checkbox"  checked={isChecked}
  onChange={handleOnChange}/>
```

and my function is this

```
 const handleOnChange = () => {
  let element:any = document.querySelector('input');
 element.onkeydown = (e: { key: any; })  => alert(e.key);
element.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keydown',{'key':'Shift'}));
  setIsChecked(!isChecked);


 
};
```

This checkbox is created dinamically as I add new rows and I would like to simulate holding the key "shift" so that when I check multiple checkboxes these rows remain selected.

I am using reactjs.

Answer (score 0):

There's no native way to do it but you can implement it based on the index you have checked.

```
const checkboxes = new Array(20).fill(null);

export default function App() {
  const [checked, setChecked] = useState([]);
  const lastChecked = useRef(null);
  const handleChange = useCallback((e) => {
    const index = Number(e.target.dataset.index);

    if (lastChecked.current !== null && e.nativeEvent.shiftKey) {
      setChecked((prev) => {
        const start = Math.min(lastChecked.current, index);
        const end = Math.max(lastChecked.current, index);
        return uniq([...prev, ...range(start, end), end]);
      });
      return;
    }
    if (e.target.checked) {
      lastChecked.current = index;
      setChecked((prev) => [...prev, index]);
    } else {
      lastChecked.current = null;
      setChecked((prev) => prev.filter((i) => i !== index));
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {checkboxes.map((_, i) => (
        <div key={i}>
          <label>
            <input
              checked={checked.includes(i)}
              data-index={i}
              type="checkbox"
              onChange={handleChange}
            />
            checkbox {i}
          </label>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: uniq and range are not recognized are you using a 3rd part library?

Comment: Yes, it's lodash' methods.

Comment: I have too many ts errors like  lastChecked.current = index (Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'null)   const start = Math.min(Number(lastChecked.current), index);(I had to make a cast to number here(otherwise error:Argument of type 'null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number')

Comment: and also (Argument of type '(prev: never[]) => number[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<never[]>'.) for the line   setChecked((prev) => [...prev, index]);

Comment: it's not production ready code. you'll need to take the concept I've implemented and shape it the way you need.